# In tcl how to use bind with ttk::treeview for right click

Tags: treeview, tcl, tk-toolkit, ttk

I have a ttk::treeview in my application, in which for nodes under a particular parent node, i want to add context menu for right click for a copy option. But I can't to make the normal bind method work with the whole tree directly.

```
bind .tree <B3-ButtonRelease> "::gui::NotebookShowTreeContextMenu %x %y %X %Y .tree"
```

I have seen in the treeview documentation that tags can used to bind mouse click but not right mouse click.
what is the correct way for implementing a right click context menu on whole tree/ particular nodes? please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.tree.body` as the window that you bind...